# Как в gitlab настроить pull request?

Tags: gitlab, непрерывная-интеграция, gitlab-ci

**Вводное**

комьюнити - сервер гитлаб 13.8.1(на текущий момент) на своей железке.

**Задача**

После создания пулл - реквеста выполнять рассылку членам команды с просьбой апрува Автоматически сливать ветку в мастер после двух апрувов от произвольных членов команды

Наверняка эта задача тривиальная и типовая. Но сколько ни искал по форуму, документациям, так и не нашёл решения. Возможно не те слова использую.

Comment: [доки](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html) уже читал?

Comment: Конечно же читал. Зачастую приводится ссылка на несуществующие у меня элементы управления. Либо доки устаревшие, либо для Enterprise версии. По докам не удалось настроить.

Comment: Например у меня нет  eligible user хотя  Introduced in GitLab Starter 11.5

To enable this merge request approval rule:

Navigate to your project’s Settings > General and expand Merge request approvals.
Locate Any eligible user and choose the number of approvals required.

Comment: Там же написано, что это правило появляется только если есть [code owners](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/code_owners.html)... но тебе оно скорей всего не нужно — это чтобы разные люди имели права на аппрув разных вещей, например, кто-то будет аппрувить только морду, кто-то — потраха, а кто-то всё...

Comment: по идее тебе нужно просто добавить своё правило, как написано [чуть ниже](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/merge_request_approvals.html#adding--editing-a-default-approval-rule), аппрувы это должно включить т.е. чтобы запрос было возможно слить надо будет сначала набрать их определённое количество... а вот на счёт автоматического мерджа в этом случае я что-то действительно ничего не вижу...